# How to delete a file in Azure blob storage

Tags: go, azure-blob-storage

I'm having a hard time finding examples of deleting a file stored in Azure blob storage using Go. The only example is a code extract [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-go?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdeveloper%2Fgo%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdeveloper%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&tabs=linux) showing how to delete the entire container.
Any help is appreciated and if possible may you share links to resources with more detailed examples in Go.

Comment: Read the godoc reference here: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-go/azblob#BlobURL.Delete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [azblob](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-go@v0.14.0) package I see that there is a [Delete](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-go@v0.14.0/azblob#BlobURL.Delete) method for the [BlobUrl](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-go@v0.14.0/azblob#BlobURL) type, which marks the blob for deletion during the GC. It internally refers to the [Delete Blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delete-blob) API call.